# Difference between DOMDocument::createElement by itself and paired with appendChild

Tags: php, domdocument

What is the difference between

```
    $table = $doc->createElement('table');
    $doc->appendChild($table);

    $tr = $doc->createElement('tr');
    $table->appendChild( $tr );

    $td = $doc->createElement('td');
    $tr->appendChild($td);
```

and

```
    $table = $doc->createElement('table');

    $tr = $doc->createElement('tr');
    $table->appendChild( $tr );

    $td = $doc->createElement('td', 'Competition');
    $tr->appendChild($td);
```

Is it really necessary to have the first append child? It seems to work without it, but I don't see any noticeable changes when I remove it. I just want to confirm it's the same thing in that case.

What about other single tags?

```
$p1 = $doc->createElement('p', 'test text1');
$p2 = $doc->createElement('p', 'test text1');
```

Would it be necessary to create an append child for each `$p1` and `$p2`?

Comment: I can see a important difference, but perhaps is unintended. On the second version you never adds $table to the tree. Thats probably a bug.

Comment: It was intended. Both work exactly the same is what I mean even though it's lacking an `appendChild()` on the second example.

Comment: How can both work the same? $table is never inserted anywhere, its a orfan object that will be destroyed by the garbage collector. While on the top $doc->appendChild($table); will make sure $table survive longer, because it will be linked to $doc, so will not be eaten by the garbage collector.

Comment: @Tei Take a look for yourself, it doesn't get destroyed:

http://codepad.org/lzndEdoW

Comment: If you are going to do that, then    $doc->appendChild($table); does nothing. You can delete that line, because you will not use the $doc tree, only the $table tree.

Comment: @Tei Thank you for clarifying, you've all been very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php):

> **`DOMDocument::createElement`**
>
> This function creates a new instance of class `DOMElement`. This node will **not** show up in the document unless it is inserted with (e.g.) `DOMNode::appendChild()`.

Therefore you must call [`DOMNode::appendChild()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.appendchild.php) to insert the node into the document.  Running your second block of code will not do so (*Tested under: PHP 5.3.5, libxml 2.7.7*).

Comment: That's weird  considering it still works. I guess I'm just confused why it works without it.

Comment: @Tek - What do you mean by still working? You output the raw XML/HTML and it shows up? Or you can interact with it in the PHP?

Comment: Both. http://codepad.viper-7.com/hOcCSt The only ones that absolutely need it are $tr and $td or else they wouldn't know where to go under. Otherwise none of the other tags need `appendChild()`

Comment: @Tek:  You're passing the nodes you want to output to `DOMDocument::saveXML()`.  Normally, one wants to output the entire document and does not include an argument for that method.  Your code does exactly as it is suppose to.